# Wayona mini USB Wireless adapter not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I have installed Ubuntu 14.0 LTS. How do i activate my Wayona mini USB Wireless adapter. I'm new to ubuntu

I have already tried the following code but it asks for github username and password. I have no idea.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git 
cd mt7601/src 
make 
sudo make install 
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/ 
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/ 
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Comment: Does the git source come with any documentations ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.